# JS: get first element of a string not properly formatted

Tags: javascript

I have a series of string badly formatted like these

```
"apple" 
"white melon, "apple", pineapple" 
"coconut, "apple", banana, coconut 
"red orange","banana" 
red melon,"banana"
```

you see sometimes the quotes are not correctly used.

Essentially I don't know much about REGEX, but my intent is to **get the very first element** of each string (can be one word or more!), given the it can be "surrounded by a quote (or double quote), a comma, or nothing...

my ideal output would be

```
apple
white melon
coconut
red orange
red melon
```

i was thinking maybe :

1. strip all the strings form any quote,
2. then using indexOf getting anything before the first occurence of the comma

is that correct?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), otherwise this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: i just added my logic here, not code yet

Comment: Then please spend more time [researching](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/497418) *before* asking questions. Without an attempt at solving your own problem this is just a work order.

Answer (score 0):

[Remove the quote characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

[Split on comma character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

[Select the first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements)

```
function getFirst(str) {
    return str.replace(/"/g, '').split(',')[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx in javascript. Following code produces the exact output you need.

```js
arr = ['"apple"', '"white melon, "apple", pineapple"', '"coconut, "apple", banana, coconut', '"red orange","banana"',
  'red melon,"banana"'
];



for (str in arr) {
  var patt1 = /[\w+\s*]+/;
  var result = arr[str].match(patt1);
  console.log(result[0]);
}
```